# How to differentitae between records while parsing xml using Xpath

Tags: java, dom, xpath, xml-parsing

I have an xml like this

```
<Processed>
    <address>
        <buildingnumber> 29 </buildingnumber>
        <street> South Lasalle Street</street>
        <city>Chicago</city>
        <state>Illinois</state>
        <zip>60603</zip>
    </address>

    <address>
        <buildingnumber> 30 </buildingnumber>
        <street> West Street</street>
        <city>xxx</city>
        <state>yyy</state>
        <zip>12345</zip>
    </address>
</Processed>
```

I am using the following code, to print the values

```
DocumentBuilder builder = tryDom.getDocumentBuilder();
xmlDocument = tryDom.getXmlDocument(builder, file);

factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
xPath = factory.newXPath();

String expression8 = "//address/descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]";

try {

    xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression8);
    Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    printXpathResult(result);

} catch (XPathExpressionException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

public static void printXpathResult(Object result){

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {   
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
        String nodeValue = node.getTextContent();

        System.out.println(nodeName + " = " + nodeValue);
    }
} //end of printXpathResult()
```

It gives me output like

```
buildingnumber =  29 
street =  South Lasalle Street
city = Chicago
state = Illinois
zip = 60603
buildingnumber =  30 
street =  West Street
city = xxx
state = yyy
zip = 12345
```

But the problem is i don't know when one address is end and other start. I want that after `zip = 60603`. I know that first address is end and other address is starting. How can i differentiate between records ?

Thanks

Comment: do you know the number of address nodes appear before the relevant one

Comment: No, because in real time i am getting xml from the web, i don't know how many address records will be present... I want that for each record some how i know that the new record is starting ...

Comment: I would suggest to change your xpaht to "//address" and than iterate over the children of the result NodeList  (which are "addresses" now.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you the position of address node which has zip you know(Lets say it is x)

```
  count(Processed/address[zip='60603']/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

Then use

```
   String expression8 = "//address[x+1]/descendant-or-self::*[not(*)]";
```

Just try it.